# String appending and why the print of a different variable returns none?

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to an item to my list:'**pepperoni**' by using `append`.

```
pizza_vege=['tomato sauce','mushrooms','pepper','cheese','garlic powder']
print(pizza_vege)
pizza_peper=pizza_vege.append('peperoni')
print(pizza_peper) #The result here should show the list of pizza_vege and add 'pepperoni to it'
```

The result shown is:

```
['tomato sauce', 'mushrooms', 'pepper', 'cheese', 'garlic powder']
None
```

I don't understand why '`print`' returns '`None`' in output. Isn't it supposed to join the two sequences??

thank you all !

Comment: `pizza_vege.append('peperoni')` returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
pizza_vege=['tomato sauce','mushrooms','pepper','cheese','garlic powder']
print(pizza_vege)
pizza_vege.append('peperoni')
print(pizza_vege)
```

Which yields

```
['tomato sauce', 'mushrooms', 'pepper', 'cheese', 'garlic powder']
['tomato sauce', 'mushrooms', 'pepper', 'cheese', 'garlic powder', 'peperoni']
```

Answer (score 0):

In above, `.append` adds item to the original list and returns `None`. Instead if you want two different list for `pizza_vege` and `pizza_peper` then , you can try:

```
pizza_vege=['tomato sauce','mushrooms','pepper','cheese','garlic powder']
pizza_peper = pizza_vege + ['peperoni']

print(pizza_vege)
print(pizza_peper) #The result here should show the list of pizza_vege and add 'pepperoni to it'
```

Result:

```
['tomato sauce', 'mushrooms', 'pepper', 'cheese', 'garlic powder']
['tomato sauce', 'mushrooms', 'pepper', 'cheese', 'garlic powder', 'peperoni']
```